# SAPUI5 - Formatter Label using Navigation Property / arrays

Tags: binding, sapui5

So, I'm building an application in SAPUI5 and I cannot fix a problem.

I have in my frontend: JS, SAPUI5, FIORI and in my backend: HANA, HANAXS.

---

Here what is happening:

I have in my backend service the following structure:

http://prntscr.com/dudto4

I have in my view the following code:

```
<Table>
....
<items>
<ColumnListItem
    type="Navigation">
    <cells>
        <Label text = "{START_TIME}" design="Bold"/>
        <Label text = "{END_TIME}" design="Standard"/>
        <ObjectIdentifier title="{DESCRIPTION}" />
        <Label text="{ItsSpeakers}" design="Bold"/>
    </cells>
</ColumnListItem>
</items>
</Table>
```

I can retrieve all the fields (START_TIME, END_TIME, DESCRIPTION) but the ItsSpeakers, which is a Navigation Property to the following table:

http://prntscr.com/dudvw3

**What is the best approach for me to retrieve a property (NAME, for example) from the image above?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ItsSpeakers is a reference to a single entity you can bind as follows

```
<Label text="{ItsSpeakers/NAME}" design="Bold"/>
```

If it is an array, you can determine the desired record and return the value via a formatter function

```
<Label text="{path:'ItsSpeakers', formatter: '.getItsSpeakersName'}" design="Bold"/>
```

... and a corresponding method on your controller ...

```
getItsSpeakersName: function(aItsSpeakers) {
   // For example to return the NAME property of the first record
   return this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/"+aItsSpeakers[0]+"/NAME");
}
```

For either of these to work, ItsSpeakers will need to be expanded in your table items binding, for example...

```
<Table items="{ path: 'EntitySet', parameters: { expand: 'ItsSpeakers' } }">
```

Comment: thanks man. It worked perfetcly. One last question: Did you search somewhere for your answer or you already knew that? I make this question because I searched a lot and I could not find a thing...

Comment: Glad it helped...have had similar requirements in this past,  initially would have either seen in an example somewhere or figured out through try, test and debug